# Keep case on header names in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular project at work that talks to an API I have no control over.
It seems like that API is case sensitive on the headers, which I know isn't right but I can't do anything about it now.
The latest versions of angular seem to be changing the case of all headers to lower case, is there any way of preventing that from happening ? If not I'll have to figure out how to downgrade all that I guess.

```
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('MyGreatHeader', "value");
```

That's now sending: `mygreatheader: value` in the http request.

Thank you

Comment: My guess is that it is actually the browser that does that..?

Comment: Just figured it out, it's actually HTTP/2. In HTTP/1.1 case is respected. I can't touch the code on the server, but I have disabled HTTP/2 on the ALB for now, which fixes it. I had no idea !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually not angular but the version of HTTP, turns out HTTP/2 forces all header to be lower case.
I've disabled HTTP/2 for now to fix it, while I try to get the API code addressed.